# Log4j2 does not log to file when test project is executed using Maven (mvn clean test)

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

When running using mvn clean test from IntelliJ terminal, Log4j2 does not write to the log file. But when tests are run using TestNG play button inside IntelliJ, logs are getting written.

This happened after I published the test automation framework to a JAR file.

In the previous version where the framework classes are still within the test project and not published as jar file, it is able to write logs when running using mvn clean test.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j2 is looking for its configuration on the classpath. For Maven based projects that usually means `[projectroot]/src/main/resources` and `[projectroot]/src/test/resources` (for test). That should work for both inside IntelliJ and the maven command line `mvn clean test`.

You can also set the system property `log4j2.configurationFile` to point to the configuration you wish to use.

For Maven that would be:

```bash
mvn -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/fully-qualified-path/log4j2.properties
```

Full details can be found here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

**Update**:

I created a [working gist](https://gist.github.com/Stwissel/06e5c11bf5829fcdbbbd7318d5da85b0) for reference.

Note: path needs to be absolute, `~` won't work. Not tested on windows. Tested with Maven 3.9.2

Comment: already tried this but log4j2 still does not write to the log file when running mvn clean tst. Any other things to look at? Thanks

Comment: @GlennC Did you use `-D...` and an absolute path?

Comment: hi there thanks for getting back. I'm having an error when executing the mvn command mentioned in the answer:
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".configurationFile=/src/test/resources/log4j2.properties"

Comment: @GlennC I added a working gist for your reference. You might need to experiment on Windows with the path.  \ is an escape char, so you would have something like C:\\Users\\...\\... You might need to escape he dot too

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now when running mvn clean test. I don't know what happened and when it started to work. But when I checked the .log file, it's getting updated now. Generally your answer provides the guidance on were to check. Cheers

Comment: Glad it worked out for you